# Using PHP to extract key from value in an array

Tags: php, arrays, key, key-value

I have a PHP array that prints the following information:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => 23 
    [1] => 34 
    [2] => 35 
    [3] => 36 
    [4] => 37 
    [5] => 38 
    ..<snip>..
)
```

I have the value and would like to cross reference it with the array to return a key. For instance, if I have a variable `$value = 34` I would want to run a PHP function to return the key, which in this case is 1.

To be more specific, the array is stored in variable `$pages` and the value is stored in variable `$nextID`. I tried using `array_search` with no luck:

How do I go about this?

Comment: It's just [key()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php)

Comment: No, key returns the key the current element (from the array pointer) in the array. array_search() should return the key for an element, if it's in the array. What is it returning for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`array_search`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) is exactly what you're looking for. I'm not sure how you had problems with it.

```
$arr = [
    5,
    10,
    15,
    20
];

$value = 15;

echo array_search($value, $arr); // 2
```

Comment: there's also array_flip which will swap keys<-->values in the array. http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php Beware: keys with the same values will be overwritten by the last key/value pair!

Answer (score 0):

You could use foreach() like that:

```
<?php
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4);

function mySearch($array, $search){
    foreach($array as $key => $value){
        if($value == $search){
            return $key;
        }
    }
}

echo mySearch($arr, 3);
?>
```

Comment: for each is generally slower than array_search  https://gist.github.com/Ocramius/1290076